# which api's are available to find movie shows information?

Tags: iphone

I want to find shows of movie,show booking,price of shows, I am searching for api for that can any one tell me which api's are there for that.

Comment: Different movies have different ratings/reviews/prices for different countries, try specifying more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really related to the iPhone tag...

Anyway, you could check

- [The TV DataBase API](http://thetvdb.com/wiki/index.php?title=Programmers_API) for TV Shows
- [The Movie DataBase API](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1) for movies

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the UIWebView?